# External bootstrap popover ( https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-popover-x ) methods & events not functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, popover

I am using the Bootstrap Popover Extended - https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-popover-x - as I need modal behaviour in the popup.

I am not able to get its methods and events working.

Also, I cannot find a working demos which utilizes it with jQuery.

Perhaps someone who has already used it could provide me with some examples ?

Specifically, I need show, shown, hide, hidden events.

[added]
The demo I am looking is http://plugins.krajee.com/popover-x/demo

Comment: Being downvoted within 7 views. I would me interested to know why I am downvoted so quickly as I do not want to repeat the same mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the description of events and methods following the link to github that you provided. Also those are listed on the official page: [events](http://plugins.krajee.com/popover-x#events) and [methods](http://plugins.krajee.com/popover-x#methods)

To show the popover manually you need:

1) initialize that, say, on a page load

```
$('you-popover-selector').popoverX({
    $target: $('target-selector')
});
```

(I've noticed that you need provide `$target` in options, otherwise there is an error; target is a DOM element near which you want to show the popover)

2) invoke `show` method

```
$('you-popover-selector').popoverX('show');
```